# How to optimize simple jQuery Image Slide Plugin

Tags: jquery, optimization, plugins, structure

For a better project structure i try to store (build) all my custom jQuery stuff to plugins. Is it possible to optimize the following plugin? I know it is ;) But i need to learn...

### Plugin

```
$.fn.slide = function(options){
    options = $.extend({
        slideitem: 'img',
        prevclass: '.prev',
        nextclass: '.next'
    }, options);

    var element = $(this);

    // How many items to slide?
    var total = element.find(options.slideitem).length;
    var count = 0;

    // Hide all items but not first item
    element.find(options.slideitem).not(':first').hide();

    // Jump to next item
    element.find(options.nextclass).click(function() {        
        (count == total - 1) ? count = 0 : count++;
        element.find(options.slideitem).hide();            
        element.find(options.slideitem).eq(count).show();
        return false;
    });

    // Jump to previous item
    element.find(options.prevclass).click(function() {
        (count == 0) ? count = total - 1 : count--;
        element.find(options.slideitem).hide();            
        element.find(options.slideitem).eq(count).show();
        return false;                
    });
}
```

### Example HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="nav"><a href="#" class="prev">Previous</a> <a href="#" class="next">Next</a></div>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff&text=Image#1" width="250" height="250" alt="Dummy #1"/>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/250x250/999/fff&text=Image#1" width="250" height="250" alt="Dummy #2"/>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/250x250/BBB/fff&text=Image#1" width="250" height="250" alt="Dummy #3"/>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/250x250/CCC/fff&text=Image#1" width="250" height="250" alt="Dummy #4"/>
</div>
```

Here is a working copy you can play with: http://jsfiddle.net/T4t4z/

Thank You in Advance!

Comment: Not sure you need to. The code doesn't look like it'd more than a couple milliseconds to complete.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not so much interested to increase performance. I want to increase my technique level and learn some best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few basic things you can do that won't decrease readability and will most likely improve performance slightly:

1. Cache jQuery results.  You're using:

   ```
   element.find(options.slideitem)
   ```

   several times.  You could replace this with a cached query:

   ```
   var items = element.find(options.slideitem);
   ```
2. Chain jQuery operations.  Instead of:

   ```
   element.find(options.slideitem).hide();            
   element.find(options.slideitem).eq(count).show();
   ```

   Use:

   ```
   element.find(options.slideitem).hide().eq(count).show();
   ```

However, I would avoid trying to optimize your code too much before you run into problems.

If you need to optimize further, check out [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/), which is a pretty cool tool that will compare two pieces of JavaScript for you.